# Plotly wrongly filling gaps based on color factor in R

Tags: r, time-series, plotly, lubridate

I am simply trying to get every month of data to plot the same color.

Plotly is falsely plotting lines that connect each factor color together, generating a giant mess on the chart.

`connectgaps = FALSE` does not work, because the gaps are not in the data. They are being generated by plotly on the ~factor(month), which colors each month the same.

This has something to do with multiple observations of the factor, rather than just one. If the factor was based on year, rather than month, no line traces would occur.

How can I remove these lines? Thank you!

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(plotly)

start_date <- as.Date('2020-1-1')  
end_date <- as.Date('2023-2-5')   

d1 <- tibble::tibble(date = seq(min(start_date), max(end_date), by = "1 day"))
d2 <- tibble::tibble(rnorm(1132,2))
d3 <- data.frame(d1,d2)
d3 <- d3 %>% mutate(month = month(date)) 

colnames(d3) <- c('date', 'var', 'month')

plot_ly(d3, x = ~date, y = ~var, type = "scatter", mode = "lines", color = ~factor(month), connectgaps =FALSE)
```

Comment: But you are getting that results, right? You have like 365 values per year for 23 years which makes it a bit of a mess right? Maybe you want to use subplots?

Comment: @Quinten, no. I edited the example down to 3 years to make the problematic lines more distinct. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add another column which is the year so you can group on each year using `group_by` to prevent connecting the lines per month for each year like this:

```r
start_date <- as.Date('2020-1-1')  
end_date <- as.Date('2023-2-5') 

library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)

d1 <- tibble::tibble(date = seq(min(start_date), max(end_date), by = "1 day"))
d2 <- tibble::tibble(rnorm(1132,2))
d3 <- data.frame(d1,d2)
d3 <- d3 %>% mutate(month = month(date),
                    year = year(date)) 

colnames(d3) <- c('date', 'var', 'month', 'year')
d3 %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  plot_ly(x = ~date, y = ~var, type = "scatter", mode = "lines", color = ~factor(month))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-02-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Idea nr. 2:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(plotly)

d3 %>% 
  mutate(year = year(date)) %>% 
  group_by(year) %>% 
  plot_ly(x = ~ yday(date)) %>% 
  add_lines(y = ~var,
            color = ~ factor(month))
```

[image]

To answer you question with the lines:
In ggplot when we use `group = 1` like:

```
ggplot(d3, aes(x = date, y = var, group = 1, color = factor(month)))+
  geom_line()
```

We get:
[image]

Comment: That's a cool chart, but I want to keep the trend intact and just remove the gap connections, not averaging out the data.

Comment: Ok. Please see my update. Maybe you are looking for something like this.

Comment: I need it to color each month over multiple years the same color, and not add a bunch of line gap connections.

Comment: ggplotly(ggplot(d3, aes(x = date, y = var, group = 1, color = factor(month)))+
  geom_line()) , Lines come back...